# .SetTargeting keywords within the url pathname

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am wanting to target the keywords in the pathname of a url using key values in google ad manager.

The url updates and changes based on filters users select and the order in which they are selected.

[www.examplesite.com/sports/science/gold/silver](http://www.examplesite.com/sports/science/gold/silver) or [www.examplesite.com/gold/silver/sports/science](http://www.examplesite.com/gold/silver/sports/science)

These can be in any order based on the order in which the filters are selected, so I need to be able to target each value individually no matter where it appears in the url.

Would the below script inserted into the GPT tag achieve this?

```
var keywords = window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean);
for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
  googletag.pubads().setTargeting('page_keyword', keywords[i]);
}
```

Many thanks!

Unable to try in a live environment at the moment.